# What is the error here I am unable to debug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB and Mongoose Error: Operation `users.insertOne()` Buffering Timed Out

Description:

I'm new to MongoDB and Mongoose, and I've encountered an error that I can't seem to resolve. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
[const err = new MongooseError(message);
          ^
MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (F:\Work\Information\WEB DEVELOPMENT\New folder\mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Node.js v18.18.0]
```

**Code:**

1. **script.js**:

```js
import User from './User.js';
import mongoose from "mongoose"

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});

run();
async function run() {
    const user = new User({ name: "John", age: 26 });
    await user.save(); // You should call save on the user object, not the User model
    console.log(user);
}
```

2. **User.js**:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

**Problem:**

I'm trying to learn MongoDB and Mongoose, and my goal is to create a simple user document and save it to the database. However, I'm encountering this error, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

**What I've Tried:**

- Checked the MongoDB server is running.
- Verified that the connection URL in `mongoose.connect` matches my MongoDB server's address and port.
- Disabled IPv6 in the connection settings.
- Confirmed there are no firewall rules blocking the connection.

**Additional Information:**

- Node.js version: 18.18.0
- MongoDB version: [Your MongoDB version]

I'd appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue and understanding what might be causing the timeout error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `mongoose.connect` returns promise, you have to wait for it complete (using `await` or `then/catch`) then perform any CRUD operations. [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do to wait for the connection

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
}).then(() => {
  run();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**:

You have an error in your connection that isn't being caught. The `buffering timed out after 10000ms` is a generic message returned by the Model because mongoose lets you use models without throwing an error. See [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering). You need to find out why you can't connect to the database.

Create a basic connection module and import it before you execute your `run()` function. Don't bundle your logic inside the `then` block as this will quickly lead to issues once you start adding route handlers. This way you can ensure the asynchronous call by `mongoose.connect` has been completed and any error caught. A really simple example would be:

**dbConnect.js**

```
const dbConnect = async () => {
  try {
    // await the connection
    const con = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB');
    console.log(`Connected to mongodb: ${con.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    throw(error); //< If mongoose doesn't connect throw the error
  }
}

export default dbConnect;
```

Then in your **script.js**:

```js
import User from './User.js';
import dbConnect from './dbConnect.js'; //<Import the function

try{
   dbConnect(); //< Execute the function
}catch(e){
   console.log(e); //< Catch the error thrown and log it. See why you can't connect
}

run();
async function run() {
    const user = new User({ name: "John", age: 26 });
    await user.save(); // You should call save on the user object, not the User model
    console.log(user);
}
```

This will help you when you start to use a server like express and handle requests. Just make sure you put them below the `dbConnect();` `try/catch` block.

Comment: @Ainz you're welcome. What was the error?